# Sending slowlogs to .csv file?

Tags: csv, logstash

I am using logstash 2.4.0 and logstash 2.4.0
I want to send the slowlogs to .csv output file using logstash. my config file is like this

```
      input {
  file {
    path => "D:\logstash-2.4.0\logstash-2.4.0\bin\rachu.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
   grok {
        match => [ "message", 

"\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:QUERY}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:QUERY1}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:INDEX-NAME}\]\[%{DATA:SHARD}\]%{SPACE}took\[%{DATA:TOOK}\],%{SPACE}took_millis\[%{DATA:TOOKM}\], types\[%{DATA:types}\], stats\[%{DATA:stats}\],search_type\[%{DATA:search_type}\], total_shards\[%{NUMBER:total_shards}\], source\[%{DATA:source_query}\], extra_source\[%{DATA:extra_source}\],"]
   }
}
output {
   csv {
      fields => ["TIMESTAMP","LEVEL","QUERY","QUERY1","INDEX-NAME","SHARD","TOOK","TOOKM","types","stats","search_type","total_shards","source_query","extra_source"]
      path => "D:\logstash-2.4.0\logstash-2.4.0\bin\logoutput.csv"
      spreadsheet_safe => false
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csv` filter is not useful in your context. Its goal is to parse incoming CSV data, but that's not what you have. What you need is to parse the log lines with a `grok` filter first and only then you'll be able to send it properly to the `csv` output:

```
filter {
   grok {
      match => {"message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LOGLEVEL} \]\[%{DATA:QUERY}\] \[%{WORD:QUERY1}\] \[%{WORD:INDEX}\]\[%{INT:SHARD}\] took\[%{BASE10NUM:TOOK}ms\], took_millis\[%{BASE10NUM:took_millis}\], types\[%{DATA:types}\], stats\[%{DATA:stats}\], search_type\[%{DATA:search_type}\], total_shards\[%{INT:total_shards}\], source\[%{DATA:source}\], extra_source\[%{DATA:extra_source}\]"}
   }
}
output {
   csv {
      fields => ["TIMESTAMP","LOGLEVEL","QUERY","QUERY1","INDEX-NAME","SHARD","TOOK","took_millis","types","stats","search_type","total_shards","source_query","extra_source"]
      path => "F:\logstash-5.1.1\logstash-5.1.1\finaloutput1"
      spreadsheet_safe => false
   }
}
```

Note: this doesn't yet work on Logstash 5.1.1 because of [this open issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-csv/issues/10). It should get fixed soon, but in the meantime this works on Logstash 2.4.

Comment: yeah, it perfectly fitted for my need in logstash 2.4.0 and also i accepted it.

Comment: When i accepted it is showing `Thanks for feedback,votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation is recorded,but don't change the publicly displayed post score`

Comment: yeah,it got accepted now.Thanks for boosting my reputation for my question..val

Comment: Hint: message must be written correctly, else the fields can not be read.
That was a mistake I made.