# Using logstash how can i get the values that are in [ ] to .csv file?

Tags: csv, logstash

I want to send the log values that are in [ ] to .csv file without any " " on text.

```
    input {
  file {
    path => "D:\logstash-5.1.1\logstash-5.1.1\bin\slowlog.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "\[(?<TIMESTAMP>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<LEVEL>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<QUERY>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<QUERY1>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<INDEX-NAME>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<SHARD>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<TOOK>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<TOOKM>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<types>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<stats>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<search_type>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<total_shards>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<source_query>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<extra_source>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*,"]
  }
}

output {
      csv {
      fields => ["TIMESTAMP","LEVEL","QUERY","QUERY1","INDEX-NAME","SHARD","TOOK","TOOKM","types","stats","search_type","total_shards","source_query","extra_source"]
       path => "D:\logstash-5.1.1\logstash-5.1.1\bin\output.csv"
      spreadsheet_safe => false
   }

}
```

My output file is like this :

```
2017-01-18T14:05:47.376Z PC147594 [2017-01-13 12:58:09   --column 1
843][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Spectra] [testindex-stats][2]  --column 2
took[15.3ms]     --column 3
took_millis[15]  --column 4
types[]          --column 5
stats[]          --column 6
search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH]    --column 7
total_shards[5]                  --column 8
source[{"query":{"match":{"text":"ronin"}}}]     --column 9
extra_source[]  --column 10
```

But what i want is

```
2017-01-13 12:58:09,843]  --column 1
WARN                      --column 2
index.search.slowlog.query --column 3
Spectra                    --column 4
testindex-stats            --column 5
2                          --column 6
15.3ms                     --column 7
so on..                       column..
```

I think this was a problem in logstash 5.1.1 .

Comment: The issue is not a problem of separators, see this question to find out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681873/sending-slowlogs-to-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a grok pattern like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "\[(?<field1>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field2>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field3>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field4>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field5>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field6>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field7>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field8>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field9>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field10>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field11>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field12>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field13>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*\[(?<field14>[^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*"]
  }
}
```

And then you'd use the csv output like this:

```
 output {
   csv => { 
    fields => ["field1","field2","field3","field4","field5","field6","field7","field8","field9","field10","field11","field12","field13","field14"] 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it is problem with logstash 5.1.1 ,i updated my question

Comment: If I change the filenames to unix style and run on my mac, there is no syntax error, so not sure what issue you are having.  Also when you updated the fields on csv output to be a specific list of names, you have to update the top pattern to match the same names in the grok pattern.

Comment: I updated the question by changing the grok pattern names but the output is the same no change..

Comment: Change your \ to / in your filenames

Comment: you want to write like this "D:/logstash-5.1.1/logstash-5.1.1/bin/output.csv"